# Два деепричастных оборота при сказуемом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*С другой стороны, не хочется потратить впустую ещё два года(,) протирая штаны на нудных лекциях(,) бездумно листая ленту соцсетей.*

Первую запятую я бы не ставил: оборот тесно связан со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания. Вторая запятая тоже, по моему мнению, не ставится: второй деепричастный оборот тесно примыкает к первому. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 3):

Распространенный деепричастный оборот (1) обособляется в обязательном порядке (это не наречное выражение). Желательно связать два оборота союзом И, тогда конструкция  лучше смотрится графически и читается лучше:

**С другой стороны, не хочется потратить впустую ещё два года, протирая штаны на нудных лекциях и бездумно листая ленту соцсетей.**

Comment: Дело в том, что "бездумно листая ленту соцсетей" относится скорее к посещению лекций, а не к потраченным годам. Человек протирает штаны на нудных лекциях, бездумно листая ленту соцсетей, а не тратит два года, бездумно листая ленту соцсетей. Понимаете тонкость?

Comment: Тонкость останется за пределами понимания ваших потенциальных читателей. Семантически  это примерно одно и то же: бесполезные занятия в течение двух лет. А грамматически это однородные обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами (причем деепричастия несов. вида, обозначают одновременные действия). Если хотите выразить особый смысл, то правильно подбирайте соответствующую грамматическую форму.

Comment: "Но Клим видел, что Лида, слушая рассказы отца поджав губы, не верит им". Опираясь на данный пример у Розенталя (хотя в его предложении второй деепричастный оборот имеет совершенный вид), я думал, что и можно в моём случае можно так.

Comment: Поджав губы - этот оборот здесь использован в значении наречия (= с поджатыми губами).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не просматривается тесной связи со сказуемым, поскольку без деепричастного оборота оно имеет такой же цельный смысл, который и акцентируется в предложении (нежелание потерять два года). У Лопатина на эту тему рассматриваются исключения, когда деепричастие примыкает к глаголу и вместе с зависимыми словами придаёт его действию законченный смысл (*Упражнение делают сидя на стуле.* Ср. *Не хотелось бы ещё два года сидеть протирая штаны.*)

Вторая запятая тоже нужна, поскольку второй деепричастный оборот не образуют устойчивого выражения, эквивалентного обстоятельству образа действия (напр. "сломя голову").

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=196

Comment: Но это нормально, что по смыслу деепричастный оборот относится к другому деепричастному обороту (второй к первому), а не к инфинитиву?

Comment: Он грамматически не относится к первому обороту. Если по смыслу нужно эти части подчинить, то первый оборот можно преобразовать в обычную глагольную форму: _С другой стороны, не хочется потратить впустую ещё два года и протирать штаны на нудных лекциях, бездумно листая ленту соцсетей._

Comment: "Но Клим видел, что Лида, слушая рассказы отца поджав губы, не верит им". Опираясь на данный пример у Розенталя (хотя в его предложении второй деепричастный оборот имеет совершенный вид), я думал, что и можно в моём случае можно так.

Comment: Здесь устойчивое _поджав губы_ эквивалент наречия (слушать как), поэтому не отделяется.

Answer (score 2):

Два обычных (как мне кажется) деепричастных оборота, которые [**обособляются на общих основаниях**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/).

Вот некоторые похожие предложения.
1. За пять лет в МО РФ без войны, протирая штаны и полируя паркет, прошел "славный путь" от генерал-майора до генерала-армии...
2. Альви Джабраилов: «Сидеть и наблюдать этот бардак в горсовете, протирая штаны, я бы не смог» (заголовок статьи).
3. Всё это время я не знал, чем себя занять, сидел, бездумно листая сайты в компьютере (Л. Савельев. Три дня).
4. — Не знаю, — пожав плечами, ответила я, бездумно листая страницы, что пестрили разнообразием цветочных композиций (О. Заушицына. Небо в океане).